# Does not getting value at class level

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not sure about this cause due to DataType or Static modifier, what might causing with `By` data type:

**variableDeclaredClass.cs:**

```
 public static String userGroupName;
```

**app.config Declaration**

```
<add key="userGroupName" value="Test User Group 01"/>
```

**appconfig-ReaderClass.cs:**

```
userGroupName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userGroupName"];
```

**Executable Query-Test.cs:**

```
By getVerify = By.XPath("//td[@class='boldText' and contains(text(),'" + userGroupName + "')]");
```

Query causing me by variable `userGroupName` that `getVerify` variable is not getting value of `userGroupName` variable.

While Debugging I went through this variable and got value of Variable(`userGroupName`) as single instance. But, It does not contain for query(`getVerify`).

**Reference screenshot from Debugging:**

Debugger Checkpoint 1 with variable:
[image]

Debugger Checkpoint 2 with Query:
[image]

Is this something because of Static modifier on class level ?

Comment: Where is `userGroupName` declared?

Comment: It is declared as public static in separate class(Global variable).

Comment: And you can access it this way? don't you mean `OtherClass.userGroupName`? share all the relevant code please.

Comment: No, I have extended relevant classes, and so I am able to get Global values.

Comment: I can't reproduce from the information you provided. Can you share all the relevant data, including the code for classes and `userGroupName` deceleration and where is the breakpoint where you see this.

Comment: @Guy Thank you for looking in to it, I have added all references,as far i am using it. I can't add all code because of long complexity. Classes are extended and so far everything works fine related to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184754/discussion-between-guy-and-ishita-shah).

Comment: Dear @IshitaShah, regarding [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21764432), please note that Stack Overflow has a policy regarding [meta-tag:link-only-answers], and even a predefined comment to deal with such cases. See ["_**any link-only answer should be deleted.** It is not an answer._"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251613/1033581)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use it from method,

```
By getVerify;

public void temp()
{
getVerify = By.XPath("//td[@class='boldText' and contains(text(),'" + userGroupName + "')]");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
By getVerify = By.XPath("//td[@class='boldText' and contains(text(),'" + userGroupName + "')]");
```

You can use either:

```
By getVerify = By.XPath("//td[@class='boldText' and contains(.,'" + userGroupName + "')]");
```

Or:

```
By getVerify = By.XPath("//td[@class='boldText' and text()='" + userGroupName + "']");
```

Comment: Here issue might be with the Variable and not with the Query selector.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
string selector = $"//td[@class='boldText' and contains(text(),'"{userGroupName}"')]"
By getVerify = By.XPath(selector);
```

First you are creating full selector, then you adding it to the place, where it is needed.

Comment: A, sorry. Then just change var to string.

Comment: Then you need to make any actions with this element (like finding element, using it) in a separate method and it will part of the test case.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are different languages :(